# Terrafrom output in data= <<EOF

Tags: terraform

considering thta I have

```
      data_json = <<EOT
{
  "policies": ["${local.test2}"],
  "password": "${local.test3}"
}
EOT
```

I can output all values from it using

```
    output "test1" {
    value = values(jsondecode(local.data_json))
}

    Changes to Outputs:
  + ids1 = [
      + "bbb",
      + [
          + "aaaa",
        ],
    ]
```

But how I ca get only the password value from it?

I'm getting

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 63, in output "ids1":
│   63:     value = values(jsondecode(local.data_json.password))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.data_json is "{\n  \"policies\": [\"aaaa\"],\n  \"password\": \"bbb\"\n}\n"
│
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
```

Thanks

Comment: `values(jsondecode(local.data_json.password))["password"]`

Comment: @Marko, putting answers in comments is really equally as bad as putting comments in answers. Comments are not treated the same way as answers in terms of searching and so on, so your answers, if valid, should be posted *as* answers.

Comment: @paxdiablo Agreed. Sometimes I feel like the comment should be enough to help and I am aware it doesn't have the same weight as an answer in terms of search engine indexing. However, on multiple occasions I have found comments to be equally as helpful as the answer or providing additional context/explanation. I will try to limit the comments where I feel I know the right answer, so thanks for encouraging me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only `password` you can do:

```
output "test1" {
    #sensitive = true # <-- this could be good to uncomment for security
    value = jsondecode(local.data_json)["password"]
}
```